# How do split panes in Terminal work?

Tags: terminal

I tried to open a split pane to run another command but instead it displays the same in both panes and I can only interact with one of them. I thought it would split the view so I could use the two panes independently like two windows.

I have the Visor installed but I don't think it would interfere.

```
Terminal - version 2.1.1
Visor custom (84d1873) based on 1.5
```

Comment: This sounds like a feature request to me. Please file a report at https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/. You can use any Apple ID to access the developer site.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

It's meant to be like that. See [this Super User answer](https://superuser.com/questions/52572/mac-os-x-snow-leopard-split-terminal-windows):

> You're misinterpreting the feature. It's not meant for two separate
>   terminals. It's intended to allow a
>   user to see two different view points
>   in the same terminal. For instance, if
>   you have 3000 files in a directory,
>   and you perform an ls command, that
>   output is going to be very long.
>
> If you use the split pane, you can
>   scroll through that long output
>   without having to flip back and forth,
>   possibly losing your place along the
>   way.
>
> If you want two terminals, use tabs,
>   or separate windows.

I would add that, for two separate terminals, you can use separate tabs as well.

Comment: this is really disappointing...

Comment: There is always emacs if you are already in Terminal, but the learning curve is a bit steep.

Comment: @Mark: or `tmux` or `screen`.

Answer (score 11):

[iTerm 2](http://www.iterm2.com/) supports [split panes](http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/features) with independent shells in each pane, not one linked shell.

[image: Split panes in iTerm 2]

Comment: Supposing you use iTerm 2, would you say that it works "better" than Terminal.app + Visor for a quick "pop-in, do-something, pop-out" workflow? I am a Rails web developer if that helps to visualize my needs.

Comment: @Vrinek not sure. You could still use Visor and iTerm2.

Answer (score 4):

You should really have a look at `screen` (that´s an already installed command line tool, not a separate application), which gives you the ability to split your Terminal into two (or more) separate ones. I use that with Visor and it works like a charm. Have a look around here, there are quite a few tips on how to use "screen" on a Mac.

Comment: Have a look around here? Where?

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan Sorry, if this was not clear — "here" meant to suggest searching for "screen" on this very website.

Comment: Wow! I had no idea that the beloved `screen` ships by default..! Session splitting is covered here: https://opensource.com/article/17/3/introduction-gnu-screen

Answer (score 4):

Also don't over look tmux. Its like screen but more features I believe.

Comment: Can you add a bit more details to your answer? Why is tmux better, how does it solve to problem and where do I get it if needed?