# How to switch or close the new split Terminal pane?

Tags: macos, terminal

I stumbled across the <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> hot key which splits the Terminal into 2 panes.  But I can't find documentation anywhere on how to close the new pane or even switch the focus to it so I can use it. What are the other commands?

Comment: Related to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6504/how-do-split-panes-in-terminal-work?rq=1, but the keyboard shortcut isn't mentioned there.

Comment: See also [How do I disable Cmd-D in Terminal?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/254222/60079).

Answer (score 186, accepted):

The idea behind splitting is that it allows you to keep a certain part of the shell buffer displayed while continuing to enter new commands. So only the lowest split does allow keyboard input. To position the view on the shell buffer use the scroll bar.

You can un-split by pressing <kbd>Shift-Cmd-D</kbd>.

Answer (score 29):

Like the top answer says, to undo the split is <kbd>⌘ Shift</kbd> <kbd>⌘Command</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd>.

I just wanted to add that in general OS-X shortcuts that are done with <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>-<kbd>char</kbd> are undone (or the opposite/complement command is executed) with <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>⌘ Shift</kbd>-<kbd>char</kbd>.

Comment: I'm not going to vote to close - whilst it's not really an answer, it does add a useful snippet of information.

Answer (score 0):

In the most current version of Iterm2, navigate to `Preferences > Profiles > Keys`.

Select the `+` sign and add new key shortcut. Then scroll to the bottom and select `Send Escape Sequence`. Do this twice and after you select escape sequence simply put a `b` in the text box for left and an `f` for right.

More information found here:

https://code.google.com/p/iterm2/issues/detail?id=1052