# How to switch input in split panel terminal?

Tags: terminal

I split terminal upper and down, I want to input the command in the upper panel, what should I do?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It would help us if you provided additional info, such as the types of devices, OS, what **specifically** you're trying to do, etc. Please see [ask] for how to ask good questions that have a better chance at being answered. - From Review -

Comment: See [How do split panes in Terminal work?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6504/how-do-split-panes-in-terminal-work)

Comment: possible duplicate of: [what are the split terminal commands](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87202/what-are-the-split-terminal-commands)

Answer (score 1):

> The idea behind splitting is that it allows you to keep a certain part of the shell buffer displayed while continuing to enter new commands. So only the lowest split does allow keyboard input. To position the view on the shell buffer use the scroll bar.

[How to switch or close the new split Terminal pane?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87202/how-to-switch-or-close-the-new-split-terminal-pane)