# Mac Terminal can't navigate between split panes

Tags: macos, terminal

### Problem

I have just bought a new macbook pro and am using the Terminal to code. I have read a lot of posts about pane splitting, but nothing answers my question (or none of the solutions have worked). I have figured out that I can open a new pane using command-d and close it using command-shift-d, however I cannot figure out how to switch between panes.

Edit: I am starting in vim, and want to navigate to the regular terminal.

Here is a picture of the editor before pane splitting:
[image]

Here is a picture after the split, but can not figure out how to navigate to the above pane to start using the terminal:
[image]

---

---

### Details

- Model: MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)
- OS: OS X Yosemite Version 10.10.3
- Processor: 2.9 GHz Intel Core i5
- Terminal: Version 2.5.3 (343.7)

Comment: Does http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6504/how-do-split-panes-in-terminal-work?rq=1 answer your question? Basically you only can interact with one pane, the others are read-only.

Comment: @patrix yes it does! thanks a lot. I have now installed iTerm2 to be able to achieve what I want.

Comment: @Vaderico faster than on SO, isn't it?

Comment: @Thomas what do you mean by SO?

Comment: @Vaderico StackOverflow

Comment: @Thomas ahh right. yes :) yes it is, was it you who pointed me in this forums direction? if so then thank you very much