# How do I get iTerm2 to split a single session, Terminal-style?

Tags: terminal, bash, iterm, zsh

In iTerm2, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> adds another pane in the window with a new session. Straightfoward, useful - but not what I want.

In Terminal, I could use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to split the window with the same session. Both windows held the same data - if I put a command in the bottom, I could see it at the top. They just viewed different parts of the same session.

However, Terminal does not allow the top pane to be the focused, active window. It's just another view of the bottom session. I downloaded iTerm2 specifically because I want the top pane to be the active session, while the bottom is an alternate view. (I like having things at the top of my screen)

iTerm2's documentation states:

> iTerm2 allows you to divide a tab into many rectangular "panes", each of which is a different terminal session.

Do they really regress here vs normal Terminal?

Are there other alternatives that would give this functionality?

Comment: I’ve never understood what happens in Terminal.app? Two views of the same session? So you have a window that shows, say, whatever happened 300 lines above “now”? iTerm has independent panes. In one, you might be ssh’d I got another machine, while you’re using another for local work and a third tails some log. (edit: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6504/how-do-split-panes-in-terminal-work is useful both for my and your understanding)

Comment: As described in my post, what iTerm does is both reasonable and useful. I use the functionality plenty. However, what Terminal does is also useful in its own way. I would like to be able to do the Terminal-style single session splits in addition to separate session splits.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Any solution?

Comment: Did you figure this out?